# Operator insertions vs boundary conditions in AdS/CFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, quantum-gravity, partition-function, ads-cft

This question is motivated by AdS/CFT, but really it's just about AdS quantum gravity. Consider quantum gravity in asymptotically AdS spacetime. For simplicity, assume there are no matter fields: the metric is the only field present. Now, the gravitational partition function $Z$ can be "probed" in two, seemingly distinct, ways:

1. Choose an operator $O(x)$ at the conformal boundary, and a source function $J(x)$, and insert $e^{i\int J(x)O(x)}$ into the path integral. The case I'm most interested in is when we choose $O$ to be the metric operator $g_{\mu\nu}$, in which case we write our source as $J_{\mu\nu}$, with indices. The resulting partition function is:
   $$\tag{1} Z_{sourced}[J_{\mu\nu}]\equiv \int Dg e^{i(S[g]+\int J^{\mu\nu}(x)g_{\mu\nu}(x))}.$$
2. Impose boundary conditions on the subleading behaviour of the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ near the conformal boundary. Schematically, I'll write $h_{\mu\nu}(x)$ to denote the appropriate information about the subleading behaviour (perhaps the second coefficient in the Fefferman-Graham expansion?), but I admit I don't know exactly how this works. Anyway, schematically the partition function is:
   $$Z_{GKPW}[h_{\mu\nu}]\equiv\tag{2} \int_{g_{\mu\nu}\to h_{\mu\nu}} Dg e^{iS[g]}.$$
   I named it $Z_{GKPW}$ since this is the type of partition function which appears in the GKPW dictionary, but it seems that in that context, usually only the leading saddle-point behaviour is kept:
   $$\tag{3} Z_{GKPW}[h_{\mu\nu}] \approx Z_{GKPW}^{(0)}[h_{\mu\nu}] \equiv \exp{iS_{cl}[h_{\mu\nu}]},$$ where $S_{cl}[h_{\mu\nu}]$ is the value of the action evaluated on the classical solution with boundary conditions $h_{\mu\nu}$.

I want to know the relation between these two methods of probing the partition function. My guess is the partition functions are equal if we set $J_{\mu\nu} = h_{\mu\nu}$. That is: $$\tag{5} Z_{sourced}[h_{\mu\nu}] = Z_{GKPW}[h_{\mu\nu}].$$ But perhaps this is only true in the saddle point approx, so we can only say $$\tag{6}Z_{sourced}[h_{\mu\nu}] = Z_{GKPW}^{(0)}[h_{\mu\nu}] + ...$$ where $...$ denotes quantum corrections. I'd like someone to confirm and justify whether or not (5) or (6) is true. If they're both false, is there some other way to relate $Z_{sourced}$ and $Z_{GKPW}$?

Comment: I believe the following paper discusses exactly what you want: https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.2054

Comment: There's no metric opetator. Only a stress tensor operator sourced by the metric.

Comment: @ConnorBehan why can't there be a metric operator acting at the boundary? Sure, it's not invariant under large diffeos, but we don't care since these aren't gauge transformations - they're genuine symmetries.

Comment: Let me put it this way. A two point function of the metric (or any other bulk field) will approach a power law at distances much larger than the AdS radius. Therefore, if (1) were correct, the things computed from it by taking $J$ derivatives would vanish identically.

Comment: Ok so evidently we must use some limiting procedure where we scale $J(x)$ by the correct power as $x$ is taken to the conformal boundary, so as to get a sensible finite limit for the two point function. If not, then how else are we going to insert operators at the conformal boundary? There surely should be *some* way to do so, since we'd like to be able to talk about operators living at infinity (e.g. the ADM energy).

Comment: The only way I know is GKPW's prescription of inserting quantities which make sense as operators in the dual CFT. That would mean the stress tensor in this case. But yeah, it would be nice to see a version of it which doesn't refer to AdS/CFT. Because the key point is just that you cannot get boundary modes of a field by evaluating it at a special position.

Comment: "You cannot get boundary modes of a field by evaluating it at a special position" what does it mean to "get a boundary mode"? I find it hard to believe people don't know how to act with $H_{ADM}$ (say) in the path integral picture.

Comment: People (other than me) definitely know how to. And that is precisely because $H_{ADM}$ and such are operators soruced by fields on the boundary rather than being equal to fields on the boundary. In a cut off flat space, a field can be its own source because the flat space Laplacian can evolve $\phi(x, 0)$ towards $\phi(x, z)$. But they are different objects in AdS.

Comment: Why can't operators at the boundary can be written in terms of products of fields etc? E.g. I can write $H_{ADM} = \lim_{\rho \to \pi/2} (cos\rho)^{2-d}\int d^{d-1}\Omega h_{tt}$. That's an expression in terms of the field $h_{\mu\nu}$, isn't it? Now just insert that expression into the path integral.